# Clarification of my proof regarding closed nowhere dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have to prove that "A closed set $F$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is nowhere dense iff every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cluster point of its complement" ($\mathbb{R}^n$ being seen as a metric space with the usual metric).

Here it is my proof, in which I never use the hypothesis of $F$ being closed:

$\Rightarrow$ ] Let $x$ be a point of the space, and let's suppose there exists a number $r > 0$ such that the deleted neighbourhood $B_{r}(x)-\{x\}$ and the complement of $F$ are disjoint, i.e. $B_{r}(x)-\{x\} \subseteq F$. Since the set $U := B_{r}(x)-\{x\} $ is open (it is obtained from removing a finite number of points from an open set) and since in the euclidean space we can find points different from the center in every open ball, we can consider a point $z \in U $ and a number $s >0$ such that $\emptyset \not= B_{s}(z) \subseteq U \subseteq F$,
contradicting the fact F cannot contain any non-void open set.

$\Leftarrow$ ] Now let's suppose that every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cluster point of its complement, and suppose there exists $U \not= \emptyset $ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contained in $F$. Let then $z \in U$ and $r>0$ be such that $B_{r}(z) \subseteq U$. Then, $(B_{r}(z)-\{z\}) \cap F ^c \subseteq B_{r}(z) \cap F^c = \emptyset $,
thus $(B_{r}(z)-\{z\}) \cap F ^c = \emptyset $, contradicting $z$ being a cluster point of the complement of $F$.

I see nothing wrong on my proof, then I don't know if there's really a mistake or if the hypothesis of $F$ being closed is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the second half. You want to assume that $F$ is not nowhere dense in order to get a contradiction, so you suppose that $F$ contains a non-empty open set $U$. The problem is that when you say that a set $E$ is nowhere dense in a space $X$, you mean that the **closure** of $E$ has empty interior, not just that $E$ itself has empty interior. Thus, to say that your set $F$ is not nowhere dense in $\Bbb R^n$ you must assume that $\operatorname{cl}F$ contains a non-empty open set.

For an easy counterexample when $F$ is not closed just let $n=1$ and $F=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I agree. With that said, my proof will be completed if I just add in the second half "since $F$ is closed, $F$ equals it's closure", right? And thank you very much for the feedback !

Comment: @AmélieB.: Yes, that’s exactly what was missing. And you’re very welcome!